# How to change from date format to number in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, date, numbers, format

I store items in a dictionary with the key being a date e.g. '2012/05/11'
The key is then changed to a number (41040) by default.
When I want to retrieve that item, I need to reference it by the number: dFRmonths.Item(41040). Since dFRmonths.Item("2012/05/11") does not exist.

I only have the date, not the number, so I need to convert the date to a number, then use the number to do the lookup.

Trying to convert a date to a number gives an 'overflow' error:

```
IntMonth = CInt("2012/05/11")
```

Any idea how to change "2012/05/11" into 41040 so I can look it up?

Thanks!

Comment: Max `Integer` vaue is `32767`. Define `IntMonth` as `Long`, and use `DateValue` instead of `CInt`.

Comment: You can also overcome this problem by converting the date to a String before using it as a key. That way, the dictionary key preserves the 'yyyy/mm/dd' format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tiny trick!

```
Sub dural()
    IntMonth = CLng(CDate("2012/05/11"))
    MsgBox IntMonth
End Sub
```

This is because ***CDate()*** is REALLY flexible.

Comment: Fantastic! Realise now that the number exceeded the Integer limit (hence 'overflow' error) - I should've used Long from the start.